# Is the scalar product defined always?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, ordered-fields

In a vector space, the scalar product has the property that $\langle v|v\rangle\ge 0$, where $0$ is the additive identity of that field. We use "greater than" and "equal" sign because the field over which vector space is defined satisfy ordering axion (ordered field).

If we define vector space over an unordered field (I don't see any example of it though but I think it can be defined as the axioms of vector space don't require any ordering property), then we don't define the scalar product, because then it won't satisfy the above inequality.

I have two questions-
(i) So, the scalar product is like irrelevant of the vector space (like it is not true that "whenever a vector space is defined, scalar product is also defined")?
(ii) Also the norm of vector also not defined always?

Comment: You are right, in general a vector space is just some set endowed with the structure of an abelian group (i.e. the addition) and a compatible scalar-multiplication, where the scalars come from a fixed field which may or may not be ordered. So there is no notion of scalar-product or norm in general. Sometimes it makes sense to define additional structures on vector spaces over non-ordered fields that behave similar to inner products, but the "positive-definite" condition wouldn't make sense anymore.

Comment: Even finite-dimensional vector spaces over the real numbers are not required to have an inner product. Even though it is always possible to define inner products on such vector spaces, depending on how the vector space is defined there may not be any particular reason to choose any one inner product as being superior to the others. In this case, unless we are doing something where having an inner product would be really useful, we generally don't make an arbitrary choice.

Comment: An inner product requires some ordering on the scalar field under the vector space. A norm depends on the ordering of the real positive numbers (its codomain).